# Qual encoding escolher para um banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Quando criamos uma nova base (independente de ser no MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQLServer ou outro) podemos escolher qual o *encoding* daquele banco, como por exemplo, **UTF-8** ou **Latin-1**.

1. Existe alguma recomendação ou esta escolha não faz diferença?
2. No caso dos *encodings* em que um caractere pode ocupar mais de um *byte*, como o UTF-8, se eu defino uma coluna como `varchar(5)`, posso guardar nela, por exemplo, 5 caracteres especiais (exemplo: `àèáéú`)?
3. O assistente do MySQL Workbench oferece diferentes variações de algumas codificações como o **Latin-1** e **UTF-8**. Qual a diferença entre essas variações?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
>   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: UTF-8 por ser praticamente um padrão global facilita a escolha.

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` por ser quase a prova de balas em se tratando de caracteres especiais. Não vejo motivos para utilizar qualquer outro tipo de encoding a não ser em algum caso extremamente excepcional. Corra do `latin`.

Comment: Essas da lista são collations, e não encodings. Elas devem ser escolhidas antes de mais nada, de acordo com o encoding, e entre as do mesmo encoding, a que corresponde ao critério que deseja, na língua em que for usada a aplicação.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A escolha do *charset* do seu banco de dados vai depender com a aplicação que irá utilizar o mesmo.

O `UTF-8` é um padrão que suporta além dos caracteres latinos, caracteres Gregos, Hebraicos, entre outros, sendo assim um *chartset* que suporta múltiplos idiomas.

1. Caso sua aplicação precise ser compatível com vários idiomas, o uso do UTF-8 garante que caracteres sejam exibidos corretamente aos usuários, não importa o idioma que ele use. Vários projetos open source ([Wordpress](http://br.wordpress.org/), [Drupal](https://drupal.org/), [phpBB](https://www.phpbb.com/)) utilizam UTF-8 como padrão por conta disso.
2. No MySQL um `varchar(5)` armazena até cinco caracteres, não importando o tamanho em *bytes*. Para caracteres internacionais, o SQL Server assume um [tipo de campo diferente](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186939.aspx) para dados: `nchar` e `nvarchar`. Para estes tipos de dados as *strings* devem ser delimitadas com `N''`
3. As diferentes *collations* são utilizadas na forma que *ordenação* e *comparação* serão executados, podendo variar de acordo com a região (ordem alfabética considerando acentos por exemplo). O `_ci` representa se o *Collation* é ***Case Insensitive*** (sensível a variação entre maiúsculas ou minúsculas) na **comparação**. Mais detalhes da implementação no MySQL podem ser encontradas [aqui](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).