# O que é collation?

Tags: banco-de-dados, terminologia

Eu nunca soube exatamente o que significa. Sei que tem a ver com a codificação dos dados que serão inseridos na tabela, mas além disso, existe mais algum motivo específico para selecionar uma *collation*?

Tenho umas dúvidas:

- Em se tratando de banco de dados, o que seria especificamente uma *Collation*?
- Dependendo da *Colattion* escolhida, posso aumentar a velocidade das consultas?
- Existe alguma recomendação específica quando ao uso? Exemplo: Tipo de dados salvos, região ou conjunto de caracteres?
- Que problemas posso ter se não souber qual *Collation* usar na hora de criar uma tabela ou banco de dados?

Comment: relacionado [Qual a diferença entre charset e collation em banco de dados?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30329/70)

Comment: @Bacco que bom que já tem essa pergunta, eu realmente confundo os dois.

Answer (score 4):

A collation ollation define o conjunto de regras que o servidor irá utilizar para ordenação e comparação entre textos, ou seja, como será o funcionamento dos operadores =, >, <, order by, etc. 
Por exemplo, dependendo da Collation configurada, o sistema irá ordenar o caractere 'ö' entre os caracteres ‘o’ e ‘p’, usando outra collation, esse caractere pode ser ordenado em outra posição. Por isso pode dar conflito ao fazer consultas que relacionam tabelas com collations diferentes. Além disso, a collation também define se o sistema irá diferenciar caracteres acentuados ou se será case sensitive, por exemplo a collation Latin1_General_CI_AS define que o sistema deverá tratar os caracteres como case insensitive (CI) e acentue sensitive (AS). Exemplos:

latin1_general_ci: Não há distinção entre letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Buscando por “teste”, registros como “Teste” ou “TESTE” serão retornados.
latin1_general_cs: Distingue letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Buscando por “teste” somente retornará “teste”. Opções como “Teste” e “TESTE” não serão retornadas.
latin1_swedish_ci: Não distingue letras minúsculas e maiúsculas e nem caracteres acentuados e com cedilha, ou seja, o registro que contém a palavra “Intuição” será retornado quando houver uma procura pela palavra “intúicao”
Mesmo que você troque o collation do banco de dados os objetos previamente criados não terão o collation alterado, para isso você terá que recriar o objeto.

Em relação a performance, devido ao fato de que cada collation tem suas regras no tratamento de strings, pode-se ter variações grandes de performance dependendo do tamanho da tabela a ser consultada.

[Esse artigo](http://www.madeiradata.com/collations-vs-performance/) cita um exemplo onde a diferença de performance foi de 10x entre duas tabelas idênticas com collations diferentes.

Qual collation utilizar vai depender de quais idiomas você vai suportar, por exemplo se você for trabalhar com linguagens baseadas em latin (européias, portugues, etc) voce pode usar Latin1_General, que corresponde basicamente ao conjunto de caracteres ASCII. Para trabalhar com um charset maior, como o Unicode, o mais importante é usar tipos de dados que suportam esse charset, como nchar, nvarchar.

Escolher uma collation errada pode implicar em problemas como:

- Gravação ou leitura de caracteres errados
- Performance prejudicada nas consultas
- Erros em consultas com JOIN ou comparação de textos