# Consulta SQL para retornar apenas se for maiúscula

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta numa coluna e que o retorno fossem apenas as palavras em maiúsculas que correspondem ao critério pesquisado (entrada do usuário), não importando se o critério foi digitado em maiúsculo ou minúsculo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspConsultaSobrenome

@Sobrenome nvarchar(MAX)

AS
   BEGIN

   SELECT

   SobrenomeID, 
     Sobrenome  
        FROM
            tbl_Sobrenomes
        WHERE 
        Sobrenome LIKE @Sobrenome + N'%'
END
```

Eu fiz assim e a resposta é tanto minúscula quanto maiúscula.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms180055.aspx   use a function UPPER

Comment: Não gostaria de converter, mas sim de que a consulta lesse apenas as palavras que já estão em maiúscula na coluna "Sobrenome" e retornasse essas palavras e as demais ignorasse.

Comment: Sobrenome LIKE upper(@Sobrenome + N'%') deve resolver

Comment: @Motta, não resolveu. Retorna também os "sobrenomes" em minúsculo na coluna "Sobrenomes".

Comment: Sobrenome LIKE upper(@Sobrenome + N'%' and Sobrenome  = upper(Sobrenome)

Comment: @Motta, Infelizmente também não. Continua retornando ambas palavras.

Comment: então me desculpe pois não entendi o problema.

Comment: @Motta, na linha existem diversas palavras. Eu quero que a consulte retorne a palavra que atenda o critério, desde que seja maiúscula.

Comment: Mostre exemplos na definição por favor.

Comment: coloquei uma imagem de exemplo @Motta

Comment: E na caso de seu exemplo é para retornar o que ?

Comment: o sobrenome que está em maiúsculo. Exemplo: ADAMI.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql   tente usar a FUNCTION CHARINDEX , talvez combinando com SUBSTR para obter sóba parte que interessa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por default a collation das tabelas é case insensitive, para saber mais sobre collation [clique aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189622/o-que-%C3%A9-collation), portanto você tem duas alternativas: ou alterar a collation da sua coluna da sua tabela

```
alter table Foo alter column Bar ntext collate Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

ou executar a consulta especificando uma collation case sensitive

```
select * from nomes where nome COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ='fulano'
```

Comment: Sim, resolveu. O resultado foi o esperado. Obrigado pela dica e pela resposta.