# SQL LIKE é Case Sensitive(Caso Sensitivo)?

Tags: mysql, sql, case-insensitive, sensibilidade-de-caixa

Ao ter esta dúvida, não encontrei resultados rápidos em português que oferecessem resposta(maioria dos resultados estão no StackOverflow em inglês).

Seria interessante ter uma resposta objetiva aqui em português, para auxiliar a comunidade.

- Gostaria de saber se SQL LIKE é case sensitive?
- É possível realizar busca case insensitive(caso seja sensitive) usando SQL LIKE ?
- Se buscar um nome com acentuação é possível que ele identifique que "Luis" tem relação com "Luís" e vice-versa?

Comment: Depende do SGBD. Qual você está usando?

Comment: Caso seja SqlServer por exemplo essa comparação depende do Collation do campo, ele que defini esse tipo de comparação

Comment: Não é o operador que diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas, é a própria coluna como nosso amigo Jeferson Almeida citou acima.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta e inclui a tag MySQL, que é o que utilizo.

Comment: Se o Collation for `*_ci` ele é case insensitive, ou seja tanto `Luís` quanto `luís` é igual. Agora, a acentuação é outra historia, que também depende do Collation, se estiver usando o `utf8_unicode_ci` irá ignorar os acentos também. Possível relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30329/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-charset-e-collation-em-banco-de-dados.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber se SQL LIKE é case sensitive?

O comando [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) apenas faz comparação de `string` conforme determinado padrão passado. Quem se responsabiliza pelo case (in)sensitive é a [`collation`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html).

> É possível realizar busca case insensitive(caso seja sensitive) usando SQL LIKE ?

Sim, dependendo apenas da collation configurado.

> Se buscar um nome com acentuação é possível que ele identifique que "Luis" tem relação com "Luís" e vice-versa?

Sim, dependendo apenas da collation configurado.

Conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/189719/766) sobre *Qual a diferença entre charset e collation em banco de dados?*, entenda o que é **collation**:

> **Collation**
>
> Collation é o termo utilizado para definir o conjunto de regras que o
> servidor irá utilizar para ordenação e comparação entre textos, ou
> seja, como será o funcionamento dos operadores =, >, <, order by, etc.
> Por exemplo, dependendo da Collation configurada, o sistema irá
> ordenar o caractere 'ö' entre os caracteres ‘o’ e ‘p’, usando outra
> collation, esse caractere pode ser ordenado em outra posição. Por isso
> pode dar conflito ao fazer consultas que relacionam tabelas com
> collations diferentes. Além disso, a collation também define se o
> sistema irá diferenciar caracteres acentuados ou se será case
> sensitive, por exemplo a collation Latin1_General_CI_AS define que o
> sistema deverá tratar os caracteres como case insensitive (CI) e
> acentue sensitive (AS). Exemplos:
>
> **latin1_general_ci**: Não há distinção entre letras maiúsculas e
> minúsculas. Buscando por “teste”, registros como “Teste” ou “TESTE”
> serão retornados.
>
> **latin1_general_cs**: Distingue letras maiúsculas e
> minúsculas. Buscando por “teste” somente retornará “teste”. Opções
> como “Teste” e “TESTE” não serão retornadas.
>
> **latin1_swedish_ci**: Não
> distingue letras minúsculas e maiúsculas e nem caracteres acentuados e
> com cedilha, ou seja, o registro que contém a palavra “Intuição” será
> retornado quando houver uma procura pela palavra “intúicao”

Answer (score -2):

Em MySQL o operador LIKE é case-insensitive por default, tanto faz se tu estas buscando Zé, zé, zÉ ou ZÉ.

No caso de comparar o acento de Luís e Luis você pode simplesmente fazer utilizar um OR, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM <tabela>
WHERE nome LIKE 'Luís' OR nome LIKE 'Luís'
```

Mais informações podem ser vistas na [documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html), em inglês.

Answer (score -4):

Para caso sensitive no Mysql é só transformar a pesquisa em binária usando o LIKE BINARY.

fonte: https://davidhamann.de/2019/02/25/mysql-case-sensitive-like-search/

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).