# qual a melhor forma de fazer uma consulta case_sensitive

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `table_users` WHERE BINARY nome = $nome AND senha = $senha
```

Isso é correto, ou seria uma má prática?

Comment: Incorreto não é, mas acho que o `LIKE` é melhor

Answer (score 3):

É um erro usar `BINARY` para este caso, se estiver armazenando senhas. Aliás, senhas [não devem ser armazenadas em DB](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70).

O `BINARY` ignora completamente o unicode e equivalência de caracteres, então um `Á` composto sempre será tratado diferente de um `Á` de caractere simples.

Em resumo: pode acontecer que, dependendo do OS e da aplicação, um usuário digite o mesmo caractere, e ele seja enviado de maneiras diferentes, invalidando um acesso legítimo, e o usuário não vai nem saber o que aconteceu.

É corretissimo se armazenar *hashes*, por outro lado. Hashes são naturalmente "binários" no sentido de poderem usar qualquer caractere de `0x00` a `0xff`. Tenho visto muita gente armazenando os *hashes* em [hexadecimal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13573/70), mas armazenando direto em binário você gasta metade do espaço.

Nos nomes, inclusive, nem teria razão para ser CS, exceto alguma restrição muito específica da aplicação. Ter dois usuários diferentes chamados "José" e "josé" é um bom princípio de confusão.

## *Collations*

A solução nestes casos é usar as [*collations*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30329/70) corretas em cada coluna do banco, conforme a necessidade.

Pode usar nativamente, especificando na criação da tabela (ou alterando-a), ou pode usar o [verbo `COLLATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collate.html) do DB na hora da query.

Por exemplo, em unicode, você tem a `utf8_bin`, que considera o código dos caracteres em *unicode*, e não os *bytes* individuais. Vale notar que ao exibir na tela, pode ser interessante forçar um `ORDER BY column COLLATE utf8_general_ci` para manter a ordem alfabética esperada, se realmente for usar isto nos nomes.

Em `latin`, você tem as terminações `_ci` para _case_insensitive_ e `_cs` para sensitive.

Entenda melhor aqui:

> [Qual a diferença entre charset e collation em banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/30329/70)

Answer (score 0):

Resposta curta: é correto e não é, depende da necessidade.
No seu caso, tratando de usuário e senha, seria melhor validar a entrada dos dados com um padrão especificado, nomes de usuário geralmente são considerados válidos apenas com caracteres minúsculos números e etc, seguindo este contexto se você sempre validar a entrada dos dados para que tal valor seja de tal maneira (sempre minúsculo por exemplo), não terá a necessidade de aplicar coisas específicas ao fazer queries para o database por exemplo.. Mas se deseja que um nome de usuário possa ter caracteres maiúsculos, aí sim essa implementação faria sentido. Espero que ajude!

Answer (score 0):

Não é incorreto mas tem consequências.

A palavra chave BINARY faz um cast da string para uma string binária, forçando a comparação byte a byte e não caracter a caracter, tornando comparação case sensitive além de tornar os espaços em branco no inicio na string significativos.

Se você realmente precisa que a comparação para esse campo seja case sensitive, é mais apropriado você tornar a coluna toda BINARY, pois uso da palavra chave BINARY na query anula a utilização do índice caso a essa coluna seja indexada. Isso sim é ruim, e no seu caso, essa coluna obrigatoriamente deveria estar indexada.

No exemplo abaixo perceba que o índice xnome não será utilizado ao se utilizar BINARY:

```
    mysql> explain select * from tb where xnome = 'a'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tb
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: xnome
          key: xnome
      key_len: 153
          ref: const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)

mysql> explain select * from tb where BINARY xnome = 'a'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tb
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 3
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
1 row in set, 1 warning (0,00 sec)
```

Isso não ocorre quando você cria a coluna como BINARY, o índice também já é criado de maneira apropriada.

Você pode alterar o tipo da coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE nome_tabela CHANGE nome_coluna nome_coluna VARCHAR(XX) BINARY NOT NULL;
```