# Qual é a diferença entre Collation UNICODE_CI_AI, UNICODE_CI e UNICODE

Tags: banco-de-dados, firebird

Existe diferença entre `UNICODE_CI_AI`, `UNICODE_CI` e `UNICODE`? Quais são e em que interfere cada uma no banco de dados?

Comment: CI = Case-insensitive, AI = Accent-insensitive

Comment: https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-collations.html

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30329/112052

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Collation*** (*Colação*) nada mais é que a codificação de caracteres existente no Banco de Dados.
Existem configurações para *conjuntos de caracteres* e **Collations** (*colações*) em quatro níveis:

1. *Servidor*.
2. *Banco de Dados*.
3. *Tabela*.
4. *Conexão*.

Quando você migra o conteúdo de uma base de dados, algumas vezes, pode haver conflitos no **collation** da base migrada. O resultado deste conflito é a ausência de caracteres especiais quando informações são consultadas no banco.

Você cadastrou a palavra “*José*” no seu banco de dados, mas quando a programação do seu site ou sistema busca este item, retorna o resultado “*Jos?*”. Ou seja, os caracteres com acentuação como (é, ã, õ, etc.) são substituídos pelo sinal ”?” (interrogação) ou outros caracteres. Fonte: https://uolhost.uol.com.br/faq/v2/banco-de-dados/o-que-e-collation-de-uma-base-de-dados-como-alterar.html#rmcl

- ***UTF-8***
         É uma codificação de caracteres com largura variável capaz de codificar todos os 1.112.064 pontos de código válidos em `Unicode` usando *de um a quatro bytes de 8 bits*. A codificação é definida pelo padrão `Unicode` e foi originalmente projetada por Ken Thompson e Rob Pike. O nome é derivado do Formato de Transformação `Unicode` ou (***Universal Coded Character Set***) - 8 bits.
- **Collation***
   Cada conjunto de caracteres tem uma seqüência de intercalação padrão (COLLATE) que especifica a ordem de agrupamento. Geralmente, não fornece nada mais do que ordenar com base no código numérico dos caracteres e um mapeamento básico de caracteres maiúsculos e minúsculos. Se algum comportamento for necessário para sequências que não são fornecidas pela seqüência de intercalação padrão e uma colação alternativa adequada for suportada para esse conjunto de caracteres, uma cláusula `COLLATE` `collation` poderá ser especificada na definição da coluna.
   
  Uma cláusula `COLLATE` `collation` pode ser aplicada em outros contextos além da definição da coluna. Para operações de comparação maior que/menor que, ele pode ser adicionado na cláusula `WHERE` de uma instrução `SELECT`. Se a saída precisar ser classificada em uma seqüência alfabética especial, ou sem distinção entre *maiúsculas* e *minúsculas*, e a colação apropriada existir, uma cláusula `COLLATE` poderá ser incluída com a cláusula `ORDER BY` quando as linhas estiverem sendo classificadas em um campo de caractere e com a cláusula `GROUP BY` no caso de operações de agrupamento.

Collation para Character Set UTF8:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -4):

**Charset** é o conjunto de caracteres disponíveis para o seu banco de dados armazenar, quase sempre ISO8859_1, WIN1252 e UNICODE. Cada qual com o seu conjunto limitados de caracteres.

Se seu banco de dados usa apenas caracteres latinos e ocidentais então o ISO8859_1(também conhecido como Latin1) tá de bom tamanho para você, mas se precisa dum conjunto grande de caracteres que permita escrever numa mesma sentença caracteres ocidentais, emojis e ideogramas japoneses(ex.) então você tem que optar pelo UNICODE, geralmente UTF-8.

**Collate** é a forma como os caracteres serão tratados e/ou ordenados dentro do banco. Será que 'A' vem antes 'á'? 'A' e 'á' são diferentes ou iguais? Será que 'Pharmacia' e 'Farmacia' é a mesma coisa? Será que 'José' e 'JoSe' também são iguais?
Quem cria os collates define isso, no Brasil não tem essa coisa de 'Ph' de farmacia, mas outros paises podem haver agrupamento de caracteres(daí o nome de collate) que devem ser tratados conjuntamente e não de forma individual.

Os collates estão atrelados ao charset porque sem eles, o banco não teria a regionalidade de ordenação, ou quais sinais diacríticos são iguais a suas versões sem esses sinais e assim por diante.

Mesmo que um banco de dados tenha uma tabela usando 3 charsets diferentes, se os 3 tiverem o mesmo collate, em teoria a ordenação e a comparação seriam iguais em todos eles. (CI_AI) significa que o collate não fará distinção entre maiúsculos e minúsculos e os acentos. Só (CI) seria apenas Case Insensitive e não distinguiria maiúsculo e minúsculo, mas diferenciaria as acentuações.

O collate pode estar tanto na definição do banco como também pode ser usado de maneira avulsa, ex:

```
select * from clientes a
where a.razao_social collate unicode_ci_ai LIKE '%José%'
```

Cada charset terá seus próprios 'collates', não dá para usar o collate de um charset em outro.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).