# Tamanho limite do campo VARCHAR2 no Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho uma coluna com o tipo *VARCHAR2 (4000 CHAR)* e estou testando o tamanho limite do campo *VARCHAR2* no *Oracle*. Achava que havia um limite de `4000 bytes` no campo, mesmo especificando o valor `4000` em caracteres, devido a esse erro já ter acontecido no trabalho e o problema ter sido resolvido.

Ao tentar inserir uma string contendo mais de *2000* caracteres **á**, ocorria um erro dizendo que o valor era grande demais para o campo. Isso acontecia porque o caractere **á** ocupava *2 bytes no banco de dados*. Porém, hoje foi feito o mesmo teste e dessa vez o banco de dados inseriu o valor corretamente.

Isso ocorreu em apenas uma das máquinas do local onde trabalho, que possui a mesma configuração das outras.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

Existe alguma configuração no Oracle que pode estar permitindo inserir uma string com mais de 4000 bytes?

Comment: Provavelmente está usando um *encoding* diferente. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21230/101 Ou se for um *encoding* que cada caractere ocupa um tamanho diferente pode ser o texto diferente que fez caber.

Comment: De que maneira ele é inserido no banco, através de uma aplicação como PL/SQL ou SQL developer?

Comment: Tentei inserir pelo SQL developer e também através da aplicação que estou desenvolvendo. A máquina em que ocorreu o problema tem Windows. As demais são variantes de Linux ou Mac. O que estamos achando é que o problema é o encoding do Windows, mas ainda não temos certeza.

Comment: Dependendo do client que está utilizando você consegue especificar o encoding. Está definição do encoding pode ser feito nos softwares client ou até mesmo na string de conexão do seu app. Você precisa trabalhar com VARCHAR2? Pergunto isso pois dependendo da quantidade de caracteres seria interessante mudar para um tipo de dado diferente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VARCHAR2 armazena caracteres alfanuméricos de tamanho variável, entre 1 e 4000 bytes ou caracteres. O tamanho padrão desta coluna é definido em bytes, *no seu caso, este pode ser o problema*.

Ao criar uma coluna VARCHAR2 podemos especificar se os dados serão contabilizados como bytes ou caracteres. Existe uma grande diferença entre essas duas opções, por exemplo, se utilizar o encode UTF-8, 1 único caractere pode ser armazenado em até 3 bytes, logo, o limite de armazenamento pode cair consideravelmente se existirem muitas palavras/letras acentuadas, nestes casos neste caso seria melhor especificar o armazenamento da coluna em character.

Maiores informações em: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm

Answer (score 1):

A resposta aceita para a pergunta é correta e a documentação tem muita informação, mas vou dar um exemplo prático pois já sofri bastante com isso no `oracle`.

Vamos começar verificando, com o `SQL` abaixo, o valor do `NLS_CHARACTERSET`, que é o "causador" do problema:

```
SELECT *
FROM nls_database_parameters
WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
```

Se você estiver usando **UTF8**, como já informado, um único caractere pode ocupar 3 bytes. Então, em um banco configurado dessa forma, se executar o seguinte SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE NLS_TESTS (
    COMCHAR VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),
    SEMCHAR VARCHAR2(3)
);

INSERT INTO NLS_TESTS VALUES('aei', 'aei'); --Será inserido
INSERT INTO NLS_TESTS VALUES('áéí', 'áéí'); --Não será inserido!!
INSERT INTO NLS_TESTS VALUES('áéí', 'aei'); --Será inserido!!
```

O segundo `insert` não será inserido, pois o `SEMCHAR VARCHAR2(3)` usa o `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` atual para determinar o tamanho do texto. Ou seja, para `UTF8` se o caractere ocupar 2 bytes, então esses 2 bytes serão ocupados de fato na coluna.

Já o terceiro `insert` será executado sem erro, pois a coluna `COMCHAR VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)` está usando 'CHAR', que basicamente indica que a coluna deve ter espaço suficiente para 3 caracteres, independente de quantos bytes esse ocupa.

Já passei por esse problema onde alterar coluna a coluna para VARCHAR2(x CHAR) era inviável, uma forma de contornar isso seria usando o seguinte código na sua transação atual, para alterar o `NLS_CHARACTERSET` da sessão:

```
declare
    v_s_CharacterSet VARCHAR2(160);
begin
    select VALUE
    into v_s_CharacterSet
    from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS
    where PARAMETER = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';
    if v_s_CharacterSet in ('UTF8', 'AL32UTF8') then
        execute immediate 'alter session set nls_length_semantics=char';
    end if;
end;
```

Isso também explica por que quando executando de outro computador funcionou. A sessão que foi aberta onde deu certo, não usava `UTF8` ou `AL32UTF8`.

Answer (score -2):

Só uma nota: se tiveres Oracle 12c, podes extender esse limite para 32767 bytes. Para isso, é necessário alterar o parametro MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED. 
Neste link tens mais alguma informação: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF55623

Comment: Sua resposta não responde a pergunta. Para fazer um comentário use o campo de comentário. Link relativo: [Por que e como algumas respostas são excluídas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)