# Usar UTF-8 ou Latin1?

Tags: mysql, aplicação-web, codificação-de-caracteres

Comecei um novo projeto e ao criar o banco de dados (MySQL), não pensei duas vezes, coloquei um `CHARSET=utf8`. A aplicação terá suporte ao português e inglês e os usuários deverão utilizar apenas esses dois idiomas.

Em um módulo em específico os usuários poderão redigir um procedimento. Ou seja, um texto relativamente longo, o qual vou usar um editor `WYSIWYG HTML`. Os usuários formatam seus textos e eu gravo o HTML no banco de dados. Para essa coluna escolhi `VARCHAR(65535)`, assim eu usaria melhor o espaço no banco.

Porém, claro, o MySQL informou que o máximo que eu consigo no VARCHAR é 21845 por conta o UTF-8 (ocupa máximo de 3 bytes).

**Pergunta**: Atualmente ainda vale a pena eu utilizar `Latin1`, garantindo que cada caracter terá apenas 1 byte? Ou isso é obsoleto e é melhor fazer com `UTF-8`?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual encoding escolher para um banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21230/qual-encoding-escolher-para-um-banco-de-dados)

Comment: @RBZ cheguei a ler a resposta que você indicou. Porém é de 3 anos atrás, além de ter algumas informações que agora estão incorretas.

Comment: Acredito que não tenha diferença da resposta do post. Mas em todo caso, vamos aguardar alguém que possa confirmar isso ! ;]

Comment: Sendo a 3 anos atrás não muda, a escolha do tipo de algo é conforme a sua necessidade (a necessidade da aplicação que cria), se fosse um encoding melhor que o outro nem existiria o "pior", talvez ele já teria sido removido ou descontinuado. E mesmo que supostamente algo tivesse mudado ainda sim o correto seria você lançar uma recompensa na pergunta já existente solicitando respostas atualizadas e talvez comentar na resposta existente afirmando que algo mudou.

Comment: Se não vai atender povos não ocidentais, e não pretende encher sua aplicação de emoticons, latin-1 é uma boa pedida ainda, é mais compacto e mais performático (pela associação 1:1 entre bytes e caracteres). Se pretende internacionalizar, pode usar alguma das variantes de Unicode. Cada caso é um caso. O importante é entender que elogio cego a UTF-8 é falta de conhecer o que acontece por "baixo do capô". Unicode gasta mais espaço para ter mais caracteres. UTF-8 custa bem mais processamento do que o Unicode "cheio", mas balanceia espaço e versatilidade (só gasta espaço extra acima do char 127).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Não existe uma resposta correta para escolha do *encoding*. A escolha deve ser feita de acordo com a sua necessidade. É por esse motivo que os bancos aceitam vários tipos.

Se o seu sistema não tiver chance de receber nenhum caractere especial, como no caso que você está descrevendo onde o conteúdo será sempre um `HTML` em que você pode, a priori, trocar todos os caracteres especiais por suas representações *Unicode* (i.e. `&#nnnn;` onde `nnnn` é o código *unicode*), então é provável que você não precise armazenar esse dado em `UTF-8`. Você inclusive pode ter todo o seu banco de dados como um *collation* `UTF-8` e apenas esse campo do `HTML` com uma *collation* diferente.

Porém, muitas vezes você não tem controle sobre como o `HTML` será gravado no campo, você não tem um filtro para converter em casos onde o usuário colar algum caractere especial, etc. Se for esse o caso, então a melhor estratégia é usar o *Unicode*.

Outra questão está no fato de você escolher um campo `varchar` ou um campo `text` para guardar esse tipo de informação. Cada tipo de campo tem suas vantagens e desvantagens, principalmente se você tem alguma intenção de aplicar filtros ou ordenações sobre esse conteúdo. Os campos `text` também podem ser indexados, mas tem um limite (prefixo) que você deve escolher para a comparação dos caracteres. Existe também funcionalidades de *FULL TEXT SEARCH* no MySQL que podem ser aplicados nos dois tipos de campo.

Se apenas for uma questão de armazenar e recuperar o dado, eu indicaria o uso de um campo do tipo `text` em que você não se preocuparia com limitações de tamanho, no caso de você não ter esse controle do input do usuário.

Outro aspecto, é que hoje em dia a preocupação do campo ocupar 1 *byte* ou 2 *bytes* por caractere não tem muito sentido dado o custo por byte de armazenamento em disco. Apenas se você tem um sistema com uma quantidade muito grande de dados que precise replicar em várias instâncias e o custo de armazenamento do seus provedor for caro.

Se essa for sua principal preocupação e não tiver certeza se o conteúdo vai usar ou não *Unicode*, escolha o `UTF-8`. Isso irá facilitar seus *scripts* de banco, suas conversões quando fizer a leitura no programa e para exibir em páginas `HTML`.

Answer (score -1):

No MySQL você tem os tipos MEDIUMTEXT (16M caracteres) e LONGTEXT (4B), então não há necessidade de se preocupar com limitações impostas pelo encoding. Padronize em UTF-8 e seja feliz :)

Comment: esses dois tipos, no caso da coluna ser opcional, elas não ocupam espaço no banco de dados desnecessariamente?

Comment: acho a resposta totalmente pertinente. Só não quero desperdiçar espaço no banco de dados.

Comment: Não, elas ocupam apenas o espaço necessário. O único "desperdício" são 3 ou 4 bytes por linha x coluna para armazenar o tamanho da string (em MEDIUMTEXT e LONGTEXT respectivamente).

Answer (score -3):

Utilize apenas latin1 se tiver a certeza que não precisará de caracteres além dos que precisamos nas línguas latinas. O latin1 deixou de ser recomendado por representar carateres insuficientes (inclusive pelos próprios criadores que recomendam o utf-8 em sua substituição). Atualmente, utf-8 é o mais indicado, pois permite codificar quase todos os caracteres de todas as línguas com 1, 2 ou 3 bytes. Raramente chega aos 4 bytes.

Comment: Por que? O Latin1 tem justamente os caracteres que você diz não ter. Até a infromação sobre UTF-8 está errada.

Comment: Eu uso latin1 (na verdade, Win 1252, quando pra desktop) pra maior parte das coisas justo por ter todos os caracteres especiais que a língua portuguesa utiliza, e ser muito mais performático que UTF-8. Seria legal dar uma revisada nos conceitos e [edit] o post para dar uma melhorada.

Comment: Porquê a informação sobre o utf-8 está errada?

Comment: Por outra, acha que com 256 caracteres consegue representar tudo o que quer? Exemplo: Experimente introduzir símbolos como € (Euro) nas suas bases de dados que diz que utiliza latin1 e depois diga se o resultado é satisfatório.